# SQL Triggers - NEW and OLD workarounds

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am creating a trigger that acts on when an insert or update is done on the table TEACHING_INFORMATION, essentially I am just taking the year field that is inputted and making sure that the same person doesn't have the same course for the previous year and if they do not allowing it. I am using the :NEW values to compare the existing data to the inputted data however I am getting an error (placed below). Here is the code I have done:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF YEAR ON TEACHING_INFORMATION 

DECLARE requestedyear TEACHING_INFORMATION.YEAR%type;

pragma autonomous_transaction;

BEGIN
  SELECT year INTO requestedyear FROM TEACHING_INFORMATION WHERE staffID = :NEW.staffID AND COURSEID = :NEW.courseID;

  IF (:NEW.year = requestedyear + 1) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20250, 'Cannot teach the same class for 2 consecutive years');
  END IF;

END;
```

Error:

```
ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers
```

I attempted to add the `FOR EACH ROW` condition to the trigger however this does not work as another error occurs stating that it is looking at too many rows as I really only need to look at one. My logic may be way off on this as I am new to triggers but any help/guidance in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: This sort of logic makes much more sense in the stored procedure that does the `insert` than in a trigger.  If you really, really want to use a trigger, you'd need a package with a collection of keys, a row-level trigger that put the `:new` values into the collection, and then a statement level trigger that iterates through the collection to determine whether any of the rows violate your rule.  That's a lot of moving pieces to deal with.

Comment: Unfortunately it is for an assignment that is requiring the use of a trigger which is a pain

Answer (score 0):

:NEW and :OLD can only be used in row level trigger (FOR EACH ROW option), so the oracle does not know which :NEW should it take. Try to add: **referencing new as new old as old for each row**. So your code should look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF YEAR ON TEACHING_INFORMATION 
referencing new as new old as old for each row
DECLARE requestedyear TEACHING_INFORMATION.YEAR%type;

pragma autonomous_transaction;

BEGIN
  SELECT year INTO requestedyear FROM TEACHING_INFORMATION WHERE staffID = :NEW.staffID AND COURSEID = :NEW.courseID;

  IF (:NEW.year = requestedyear + 1) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20250, 'Cannot teach the same class for 2 consecutive years');
  END IF;

END;
```

Comment: `REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD` you can skip since this is the default behavior in Oracle. It makes only sense if you prefer to use other references, e.g. `REFERENCING NEW AS NEUER_WERT OLD AS ALTER_WERT`

Comment: true.. but the point about it needing to be "FOR EACH ROW" is still valid and solves the immediate issue.

Comment: wrong, he will get the `ORA-04091: table TEACHING_INFORMATION is mutating, trigger/function may not see it` error in this case.

Comment: It actually just creates this error now when attempting to run the trigger:

`SQL Error: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "44761732.TRIGGER1", line 6
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger '44761732.TRIGGER1'
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested`